# jQuery / Javascript: fire a rightclick on a normal-click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i don't think so but i couldn't find a quick answer!
is it possible to show the browsers rightclick (context) menu when clicking the left mouse trigger?

thank you

Comment: Oh, call the browser context menu... Maybe if you make a `"browser" addon/extension`, otherwise I guess it's not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't emulate physical browser clicks, such as bringing up the context menu, for security reasons. The closest you'll get to is trapping the click event, which can be done with:

http://jsfiddle.net/zysZC/

```
$(window).mousedown(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 1) { // Left mouse button, 2 = middle, 3 = right
        alert('left clicked');
    }
});
```

You may also be interested in this plugin: http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/05/jquery-right-click-plugin/